# requiring editting of cells only through script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have developed a number of Excel spreadsheets in which direct editting of the contents is protected against - editting can only be done using a drop-down menu of options. The reason for this is to prevent, as far as possible, slips of the mouse when editting.

In Google Sheets it does not seem to be possible to exercise the same control as the 'user' *always* has permission edit both spreadsheet and script. [Apps Script documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection#removeeditorsemailaddresses) seems pretty clear on this: *Neither the owner of the spreadsheet nor the current user can be removed.*

Is there a work around, or am I missing a trick, that would allow editting by script only - including removing and replacing protection of course?

Comment: For example you can create [web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) that will be running under *your* account (not user), and send requests to this web app from user. In this case you can remove ability of user to modify protected cells.

Answer (score 0):

Google sheets has many options for projecting your data. I have screen shot a couple of examples below where you can fine tune down to singles cells what is protected. Furthermore, you can publish the sheets and display them as embedded tables on Google sites/slides and other hosting.

[image]

There is also this option which will prevent anyone from copying or downloading you sheet, this setting also prevent copying and pasting data.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jason. Have looked at those options but they still do not allow the sheet to be protected against the user making errors whilst updating.

Comment: Sorry Jason - didn't mean to be so abrupt, just hit the 'return' key too soon. The sheet will be updated basically by only one, not very computer literate person - high risk of unintended, and unchecked, mouse movements. As I know from experience, hence the Excel solution of protected sheets, without passwords. Now the sheet is to be published in various parts, all relevant protection in place, for information, and Google is the obvious choice - except a perhaps of but the protection system.